# A more memory-efficient way to mimick message-passing OOP in R?

Tags: r, oop

I am looking for a way to implement traditional message-passing OOP without a large memory footprint for large collections of objects.

Message-passing OOP (e.g. R6) is a vastly superior conceptual fit for my complicated, unusual, highly specialized use case than generic function OOP (e.g. S3). With mutable objects that own their own functions, the implementation effortlessly expresses the underlying mental model, and I can establish more reliable guarantees on how objects are accessed and modified. So far, my package is far easier to read, understand, develop, maintain, and trust than a previous iteration of the same project that barely used any MP OOP. There is a world of difference in the overall quality of the software.

Unfortunately, the package needs to create thousands of objects at a time, and I am running into performance issues. I started with R6 but quickly ran into speed bottlenecks. So I chose the environment-with-a-function technique documented [here](https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Performance.html#environment-created-by-a-function-call-without-class-attribute), plus some custom metaprogramming on the constructors to make sure inheritance still works. (All this is well documented in the package's design specs.) Example:

```r
new_object <- function(field1 = NULL, field2 = NULL, field3 = NULL) {
  self <- environment()
  class <- "object"
  field1 <- field1
  field2 <- field2
  field3 <- field3
  get_class <- function() {
    get("class", envir = self)
  }
  get_field1 <- function() {
    get("field1", envir = self)
  }
  get_field2 <- function() {
    get("field2", envir = self)
  }
  get_field3 <- function() {
    get("field3", envir = self)
  }
  set_field1 <- function(field1) {
    assign("field1", field1, envir = self)
  }
  set_field2 <- function(field2) {
    assign("field2", field2, envir = self)
  }
  set_field3 <- function(field3) {
    assign("field3", field3, envir = self)
  }
  validate <- function() {
    stopifnot(is.character(self$get_field1()))
    stopifnot(is.character(self$get_field2()))
    stopifnot(is.character(self$get_field3()))
    invisible()
  }
  self
}

object <- new_object(field1 = 1, field2 = "y", field3 = "z")
object$validate()
#> Error in object$validate(): is.character(self$get_field1()) is not TRUE
object$set_field1("x")
object$get_field1()
#> [1] "x"
object$validate()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Object instantiation and field access are acceptably fast now, but now I am running into memory issues. Is it possible to implement similar objects with a lighter memory footprint while still preserving the same method access syntax?

```r
library(pryr)
object_size(new_object())
#> 33.1 kB
object_size(replicate(1000, new_object()))
#> 1.72 MB
```

Comment: I am aware that there already exists at least one working group to improve the broadly reusable OOP systems in R, but its goals are a bit different than the goals of this post.